# Powershell Script to check free disk space on servers

Tags: powershell, scripting, shell-scripting

I am in need to check free space on servers but I am getting more than enough details.

DeviceID     : C:
DriveType    : 3
ProviderName :
FreeSpace    : 76691152896
Size         : 160482455552
VolumeName   :

I am having a few queries:
1: I want every drive detail, not only for drive C
2: I don't need extra details like above, I only need the DeviceID and FreeSpace and Size.

I am using the below code:
$Report=Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName '**servername**' -Filter "Drivetype=3" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {($*.freespace/$*.size) -le '0.5'}
$View=($Report.DeviceID -join ",").Replace(":","")
if($Report)
{
Echo $Report
}

The above code returns result only if the freespace of disk is less than 50%

The above code gives me the below result
DeviceID     : C:
DriveType    : 3
ProviderName :
FreeSpace    : 76691152896
Size         : 160482455552
VolumeName   :

Kindly help me on this.
TIA

Answer (score 3):

```
$volumes = Get-Volume
foreach ($volume in $volumes) { 
if ($volume.DriveLetter -notlike "") {$volume.DriveLetter + " has " + $volume.SizeRemaining + " bytes free of " + $volume.Size + " bytes total"}
}
```

Comment: And if volume not mounted on drive letter but on some dir?